# How do I tell compass this Rails' environment is a development one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment, compass-sass

I'm working with Ruby On Rails (v. 3.0.10) and using Compass (0.11.5).

I'm using two development environments:

1. The standard Rails' `development` environment, defined in `config/environments/development.rb` connected to a PostgreSQL database.
2. A copy of the development environment, `dev-sqlite`, defined in `config/environments/dev-sqlite.rb`, with the only difference being the attached database (this time a local SQLite when I'm on the run and I can't reach my development database server).

My issue with Compass is that when I'm running Rails in my `dev-sqlite` environment (using `RAILS_ENV='dev-sqlite'` before running any Rails command, **Compass seems to work in production mode, and it does not regenerate my CSS files when I change the SCSS ones as it does when I'm in `development` environment**. This makes my development work a lot harder...

I've tried to add this line to the `config/compass.rb` file and restart my local Rails server (with `rails s`), without success:

```
environment = :development if Rails.env == 'dev-sqlite'
```

In fact, even `environment = :development` doesn't change a thing.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I added the following to the bottom of my config file and it works well for me:

```
# Enable Debugging (Line Comments, FireSass)
# Invoke from command line: compass watch -e development --force
if environment == :development 
  output_style = :expanded
  sass_options = {:debug_info => true}
end
```

Then you just need to specify that you are in development environment when you run compass watch (or compile). You can do this by running `compass watch -e development --force`. As you can see, I stuck that in a comment in my config file incase I forget.

Also, be sure to enable sass in chrome developer tools to take advantage of sass source maps

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It has been some time so my project changed a lot and I would not have use for this yet, but if this happens again, I'll definitely check your tip.